# Storing the iterator of a set to user-defined type in a std::deque in C++

Tags: c++11, iterator, deque, stdset

I have a `std::set of user-defined type` which contains sorted-values based on some criteria[overloaded < operator]. I want to `store the iterator` from this set into a `std::deque` which I can use later to update/delete entries from set. 
Here's what I am doing :

.h file

```
static std::set<SpanStruct_X> spanXRange;
std::map<uint16_t, std::deque<SpanStruct_X>::iterator> mMap;
```

.cpp

```
SpanStruct_X sX;
spanXRange.insert(sX);
mMap[id].push_back(spanXRange.find(sX));
```

I assume `::iterator` is available only for std types and not for user defined and hence I get this compilation error.

Compilation Error :

```
error: ‘std::map<short unsigned int, std::_Deque_iterator<SpanStruct_X, SpanStruct_X&, SpanStruct_X*> >::mapped_type’ has no member named ‘push_back’
                         mMap[id].push_back(spanXRange.find(sX));
```

How should I get this done?

Thanks!

Comment: You declared it to store an iterator for a `deque` of your type, not a `deque` containing `set` iterators.

Comment: oops! i guess i misinterpreted the error! thanks @ShadowRanger.. that worked pretty well!